# Any Idea why i'm getting a PIL error when i'm not even importing it?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to explore more learning paths and got to using matplotlab among others, however no matter what i try, various sites, etc. nothing seems to work. If anyone could explain why i'm getting a PIL error (yes i did read the error, and did everything searches mentioned) but nothing changed, so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain it to me, been trying for several hours now.

code:

```
# Created by Simon Ranger : December 15th 2022

"""
A general expense tracker that is displayed in table format as well as statistical format

How to use:
1. when prompt enter the data you want to be stored

Desired Output:
The user can add to a variety of lists relating to what expenses they wanted, food, general, etc. which will be both
displayed in a file and the terminal.
"""

# Imports required
from pandas import DataFrame as df, read_csv, DataFrame
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import date

# create empty lists
GoodsOrServices: list | str = []
Prices: list | float = []
Dates: list | date = []
ExpenseType: list | str = []


# funct adding data to lists
def addingData(goodsOrServices: str, prices: int | float, dates, expenseType: str) -> None:
    # appending to the lists
    GoodsOrServices.append(goodsOrServices)
    Prices.append(prices)
    Dates.append(dates)
    ExpenseType.append(expenseType)


def reportData() -> DataFrame:
    expenseType = ""

    # creating the dataframe
    report = df()
    report["GoodsOfServices"] = GoodsOrServices
    report["Prices"] = Prices
    report["Dates"] = Dates
    report["ExpenseType"] = ExpenseType
    report.to_csv("Expenses.csv")

    # creating an array to loop through the data and pull the data for each section
    FoodP = []
    HouseP = []
    TravelP = []

    # reads the file that was created above
    with open("Expenses.csv"):
        read_csv("Expenses.csv", skiprows=1)

    for _ in enumerate(report):
        if expenseType == "Food":
            Prices.append(FoodP)
        elif expenseType == "Household":
            Prices.append(HouseP)
        elif expenseType == "Travel":
            Prices.append(TravelP)
        elif _:
            print(f"Error: Something went wrong!")

    # putting the data into a graph
    plt.plot(report)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return report


def main():
    # option menu for the user
    truth: int = 1
    user: str = (input(f"Please enter your name: "))

    while truth != 0:
        options = int(
            input(f"Welcome {user} to this interactive expense tracker!\nPlease select an option below:\n1. Add "
                  f"Food Expenses\n2. Household expenses\n3. Travel Expenses\n4. Display and Save the "
                  f"Expense Report\n0. Exit\nPlease enter the choice here: "))

        match options:
            case 0:
                exit(f"Thank you for using the Expense Tracker. See you next time!")
            case 1:
                print(f"Adding Food\n")
                expenseType = "Food"
            case 2:
                print(f"Adding Household\n")
                expenseType = "Household"
            case 3:
                print(f"Adding Travel\n")
                expenseType = "Travel"
            case 4:
                reportData()

        # lets the user enter the data
        if options == 1 or options == 2 or options == 3:
            goodsOrservices = str(input(f"Enter the goods or services for the expense type {expenseType}:\n")).strip()
            price = float(input(f"Enter the price of the goods or service:\n"))
            today = date.today()
            addingData(goodsOrservices, price, today, expenseType)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\General\Desktop\Codes\Python\Programs\Advanced\ExpenseTracker.py", line 17, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\General\Desktop\Codes\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\General\Desktop\Codes\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\General\Desktop\Codes\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Comment: It literally says from the Traceback, that `matplotlib\colors.py` imports Image from PIL (`from PIL import Image`). That's why it fails.

Comment: What it is strange, how do you get matplotlib without PIL? Note: usually we install pillow, which it is compatible with PIL

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thats what me and like 6 other people can't figure out, apparently pillow is apart of matplotlab but i have have a working pillow with tkinter so no clue

Answer (score 0):

pip install was originally corrupted or errored, fresh install after wiping everything worked